# Which value to use for tag_id to create EntityTag

Tags: api

I am struggling with adding tags trough the CiviCRM API to a newly created contact in an extension (trough API Chaining). The installation is running on Wordpress 4.4.1 with CiviCRM 4.7. The following PHP snippet creates the contact with Tag "Non-Profit" which is not the expected behavior.

```
$contactParams['api.EntityTag.create'] = array(
        'entity_table' => 'Contacts', 'tag_id' => array("Interessent",     "Contributor")
);

$api->Contact->Create($contactParams)
```

Comment: Could you please update your question with your CiviCRM version number?  If nothing else, I changed the behavior of the EntityTag API in https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17350, so this may be version-dependent.  Also, are you using a non-administrator account?  If so, you'll want to be using 4.7+ or merge in CRM-17350's patch.

Comment: I am using 4.7. This is running as an extensions which hooks into civicrm_emailProcessor. I am not sure if the administrator account is relevant at all. The questions is, do I use the TagName or the TagID or Name_ID like the GroupContact API asks? I have tried all combinations with no success. The interesting thing is that the give example adds one unrelated tag named NonProfit with ID 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few advices :

- when you chain, you shouldn't have to define the entity_table. If you want to define it anyway, the entity_table should be the database table - i.e. `civicrm_contact` in your case.
- Label and id of the tag can be used in tag_id but i really encourage you to use the id. The label can change or be language dependent while the `id` could not change.

But to answer your question, in your case, the real problem is the array part. The EntityTag api is to create one tag assignation. I don't think there is a syntax to assign multiple tag.

It could be nice to be able to add several `api.EntityTag.create` but because the key is the api call definition, it's impossible right now (or i don't know how).

So while this will work fine :

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'create', array(
  'contact_type' => "Individual",
  'first_name' => "xxx",
  'last_name' => "yyy",
  'api.EntityTag.create' => array('tag_id' => 5),
));
```

If you have multiple tags, i suggest you do :

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'create', array(
  'contact_type' => "Individual",
  'first_name' => "xxx",
  'last_name' => "yyy",
));
$contact_id = $result['id'];
foreach ($tags as $tag_id) {
  civicrm_api3('EntityTag', 'create', array(
    'entity_table' => 'civicrm_contact',
    'entity_id' => $contact_id,
    'tag_id' => $tag_id,
  );
}
```

**EDIT**

For multiple tags, you could try (not tested but work for website for example - https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/api/v3/examples/Contact/ChainTwoWebsites.php)

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'create', array(
  'contact_type' => "Individual",
  'first_name' => "xxx",
  'last_name' => "yyy",
  'api.EntityTag.create' => array('tag_id' => 5),
  'api.EntityTag.create.2' => array('tag_id' => 8),
));
```